# how to fix hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries

i have two pipelines and when i call another shared library i got following error-

**hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: genric.call() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), main([Ljava.lang.String;), any(groovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure)**

Followings are my both files.

```
genric.groovy file
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
//import hudson.model.*
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('build-deploy'){
            steps{
                sh''' 
                cd /home/manish/Desktop/test/
                mkdir testing
                '''
             }
         }
     }
 }

 Jenkinsfile
 library identifier: 'genric.groovy@master', retriever:          modernSCM([$class: 'GitSCMSource', credentialsId: '', remote: 'https://github.com/mani1soni/jenkins-practice.git', traits: [[$class: 'jenkins.plugins.git.traits.BranchDiscoveryTrait']]])
 pipeline{
    agent any
    environment{
        REPO_PATH='/home/manish/Desktop'
        APP_NAME='test'
    }
    stages{
       stage('calling function'){
           steps{
               genric()
            }
        }
   }
}
```

How to solve it?

### *ignore environment field*

Comment: In the link shared by Dilip it explains that you can use the vars folder with individual files for defining steps or to define the entire pipeline definition ("Defining Declarative Pipelines" section. You cannot mix these two.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax used in genric.groovy is wrong, this file should be placed inside the vars folder of shared library repo and follows the syntax described in the "Defining custom steps" section of below link:

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Comment: If it's already in vars folder then you should follow the syntax allowed to write anything on the groovy script for example: def call(String name="World") {
    echo("Hello, ${name}.")
}

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite something like this:

vars/genric.groovy file

```
call() {
    sh''' 
        cd /home/manish/Desktop/test/
        mkdir testing
    '''
}
```

Jenkinsfile

```
 library identifier: 'genric.groovy@master', retriever:          modernSCM([$class: 'GitSCMSource', credentialsId: '', remote: 'https://github.com/mani1soni/jenkins-practice.git', traits: [[$class: 'jenkins.plugins.git.traits.BranchDiscoveryTrait']]])
 pipeline{
    agent any
    environment{
        REPO_PATH='/home/manish/Desktop'
        APP_NAME='test'
    }
    stages{
       stage('calling function'){
           steps{
               genric()
            }
        }
   }
}
```